# Adding data to CandleChart(OHLC) for TeeChart(Javascript/HTML5)

Tags: javascript, charts, teechart, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to draw a `CandleStick` chart for a `TeeChart` JavaScript Version.
However I only found the below demo.
I'd like to find out how to add series(data) instead of using a `addRandom()` method.
a `addRandom(`) does not explain how to add a actual data.

if you can provide the demo with adding Json data would be wonderful.
Thanks in advance.

```
function draw() {
  Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas");
  Chart1.title.text="Candle OHLC";

  var ohlc=new Tee.Candle();
  Chart1.addSeries(ohlc).addRandom(20);

  Chart1.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find [populating series with JSON examples](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/sources/fromjson.htm) at the demo [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/), specially at the *Data Sources* section.

Candle series should be populated like this:

```
series.add(DateTime date, double open, double high, double low, double close);
```

However, with the Javascript version you should create the add function like this:

```
function draw() {
  Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas");
  Chart1.title.text="Candle OHLC";

  var ohlc=new Tee.Candle();
  Chart1.addSeries(ohlc);

  ohlc.add=function(open, close, high, low) {
    var d=this.data;
    var count;

    if (d.open) count=d.open.length+1; else count=1;
    d.values.length=count;
    d.close=d.values;

    if (d.open) d.open.length=count; else d.open=new Array(1);
    if (d.close) d.close.length=count; else d.close=new Array(1);
    if (d.high) d.high.length=count; else d.high=new Array(1);
    if (d.low) d.low.length=count; else d.low=new Array(1);

    d.open[count-1]=open;
    d.close[count-1]=close;
    d.high[count-1]=high;
    d.low[count-1]=low;
  }

  for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var o=25+Math.random()*100;
    var c=o+(Math.random()*25)-12.5;
    ohlc.add(o, c, Math.max(o,c)+Math.random()*15, Math.min(o,c)-Math.random()*15);
  }

  Chart1.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but those examples don't explain how to pass the data for the candle(OHLC) chart. As you know the candle chart requires open, high, low, close. I don't have a clue how to pass them to the chart. All the demos are only show passing the simple data to simple charts like the bar chart. Can you show me how to pass the data I mean what order? new Tee.Candle(?, ?, ?, ?);

Comment: @JosephJung ok, I have extended my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer once again, but not sure how to implement that line of the source to the above code(function draw();). The Tee.Chart object and the Tee.Candle object don't have a series method nor add. I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @JosephJung apologies for the delayed reply. You should create your own add method with the Javascript version. I have updated my reply with an example.

Comment: @JosephJung try doing as in this example: http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/series/gantt/gantt.htm